# Unity Fishnet local networking only working on Same pc

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer

I am trying to get local multiplayer in my game. I have setup everything and everything is working fine when I run the game on the same pc (multiple instances) but when I export it to order pc it doesn't connect at all .I have connecting the pc/laptop to same network as LAN. But it doesn't work it only works when I run the instances on the same pc. Any help would be appreciated. I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/oUPlKYlb27Y

The result should be can connect from other pc